# Check the type of user in database

Tags: c#, sql

I want to check whether the user is a Staff or Admin. And if the user is a staff I want to disable or hide some buttons or functions to other forms.

The `SELECT Username FROM tblAccount` in the loginsql so that I can display who is the current user to other form.

```
private void btnConfirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //DO: User authentacation
    con.Open();
    string loginsql = "SELECT Username FROM tblAccount WHERE Username = '" + txtUser.Text + "' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS AND Password = '" + txtPass.Text + "' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS AND EmpStatus = 'Active'";
    SqlDataAdapter loginda = new SqlDataAdapter(loginsql, con);
    DataTable logindt = new System.Data.DataTable();
    loginda.Fill(logindt);

    if (logindt.Rows.Count == 1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Login Successfully", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        HomeForm home = new HomeForm(logindt.Rows[0][0].ToString());
        home.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
    else if (txtUser.Text == "" && txtPass.Text == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Enter your username and password", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
    else if(txtUser.Text == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Enter your username", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
    else if(txtPass.Text == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Enter your password", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid Username and Password", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        txtUser.Clear();
        txtPass.Clear();
        txtUser.Focus();
    }
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: Consider using parametrized commands instead of string concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

you should create

1. Role Table 
   id->foreignKey To loginsql's Id 
   Roles(type is Boolean)-> for example Staff=0 or Admin=1
2. officiate Table that provide some access like delete insert update ... for users
   when the user log in you can now his roles (its admin or staff?) and did his access to see this page or not!

Answer (score 0):

Create two more tables, tblAccount already exists which contains the user's information, now Create two more tables named tblRoles & tblAccountRoles.
tblRoles will contain all the roles with their primary keys, eg 1-Admin,2-staff etc.
tblAccountRoles will contain the roles assigned to all the users for example : 1-Jeff - 1(admin), 2-zepp -2(staff) so on.
Now in your code first check if the user's login is successful by querying the tblAccount table and if success then check in tblAccountRoles table and get the roleid of the logged in user. You will get 1 for admin , 2 for staff, you can then code acc to the role id you get. You can show all the controls if the user's role id is admin i.e 1 and so on. 
Your question is a pretty basic one and could easily be searched on the internet. Do a little more searching you will find many solutions to this.

Answer (score 0):

```
    string loginsql = "SELECT Username, UserType FROM tblAccount WHERE Username = '" + txtUser.Text + "' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS AND Password = '" + txtPass.Text + "' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS AND EmpStatus = 'Active'";
    SqlDataAdapter loginda = new SqlDataAdapter(loginsql, con);
    DataTable logindt = new System.Data.DataTable();
    loginda.Fill(logindt);

    if (logindt.Rows.Count == 1)
        {
            Session["UserType"] = logindt.Rows[0][1].ToString();
            MessageBox.Show("Login Successfully", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            HomeForm home = new HomeForm(logindt.Rows[0][0].ToString());
            home.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }
```

And when you want to use the UserType to hide some information, use the following:

```
string userType = Session["UserType"].ToString();
if(userType == "Staff")
{
//Show Some data related to Staff
}
else if (userType == "Admin")
{
//Show Some Data related to Admin
}
```

I haven't tested the code, just added my code into your existing so please do test and let me know. But I gave the basic concept of how to achieve it using your existing tables etc. But you have to have 'UserType' column in the database table to have it work.

Best approach would be to make a Role table in Database:

```
Table Roles
Role_ID | Role_Desc
```

Another table for the relationships

```
Table User_Roles
User_ID | Role_ID
```

Then store User_ID and Role_ID inside this third table and access it to get the corresponding roles. In case of any queries, let me know.